# MS Access - Export Page Settings

Tags: vba, ms-access, printing

I develop an application for printing Labels.
We will use it on many workstations with different printers.
MS Access remembers the Page Setup Settings for each Report / Printer. 
Is there a way to export the Page Setup Settings?

If i write an Update, i have to setup every Report for every Printer again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export printer settings. But you should probably adjust your database to store printer preferences per machine or per machine per report in a table, so each machine can have different printing preferences.

You can export report printer by storing different properties of the `Report.Printer` object.

The main ones are:

```
Reports!SomeReport.Printer.DeviceName
Reports!SomeReport.Printer.PaperSize
Reports!SomeReport.Printer.PaperBin
```

To set a printer for a report, you can use:

```
Set Reports!SomeReport.Printer = Application.Printers("PrinterDeviceName")
```

You can set PaperSize And PaperBin by just setting the properties.

You can find some advanced documentation on working with printers [in this Microsoft Docs document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/printing/programmatically-retrieve-printer-capabilities). Note that, for me, this needed some adjustment to be able to handle printers with no trays (some virtual PDF printers).