# MS Access print margin resetting.

Tags: ms-access, printing, ms-access-2007

I am having an issue with an `MS Access 2007` `report`. The print margins for my `report` are not staying consistent.

When I open the report in print preview, I can set the margins as I wish. However, once I go to print the report, the `bottom margin` is set to a value that I did not enter.

This does not occur when I select a different printer from the drop-down menu. The printer causing this error is a `Cannon MG2900`. It cannot be switched out for a different printer.

The margin being altered is a problem for me because it causes my single-page report to split and print out onto two pages. It does this despite the print preview showing me that the report is a single page.

The printing is not handled through VBA. The print preview is brought up using VBA code, but the users have to use the `Print` button provided by `MS Access` to actually print the report.

I am using the report to print over another sheet. So it has to print out on one sheet of paper, and have a small enough margin to reach the bottom of the page.

Pictures are provided to show what I am talking about.

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: Print Window After Printing]

Notice the bottom margin in this photo is set to `0.3`

[image: Print Margins Window Before Printing]

Notice that the bottom margin has been set to `0.66`.
[image: Print Margins Window Before Printing]

Comment: could you see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943882/ms-access-export-page-settings) is of any help to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is just usual behavior.

Each printer has it's own default margins. This is because some printers can handle more narrow margins than others. By switching printers, you reset your margins to default.

If you want to force specific margins, you either need to stop changing your printer, or enforce those margins using VBA (which means you probably should switch the whole process to VBA (selecting a printer, setting printer settings, printing)). The link marlan gave you can help with that.

Comment: It is unclear to me how switching the whole process to `VBA` would help. When I set the margin for the 'problem printer' in the `gui` to any value below `.66`, it gets reset (by that printer's default presumably). How would setting it with `VBA` help? Presumably it would still be reset to the `.66` value before printing wouldn't it?

Comment: If you'd automate printing, you can store the margin before switching printers, and then set the margin again after switching.

Comment: Ahh, so let me check if I am understanding you. I'm going to call the `MG 2900 printer` `Final` since it is what I want to ultimately print on. I'll call the other one `Default`. So I currently open a `print window` that assumes `Default`'s settings. I alter those settings with no issues since `Default`'s setting don't preclude the margins I need. Then I switch the printer over to `Final` and my settings get over written by `Final`'s settings. Then the document prints before I can alter those. Changing the process to `VBA` would presumable allow me to edit the margins before printing correct?

Comment: Hmm... If you're always printing on the same printer and don't need to switch, you could also just specify that in the report settings, and not have the dialog show up at all. If you automate the process, you'd use your own dialog to pick a printer so you could specify anything you want after picking a printer.

Comment: I think I understand. Here is my remaining concern, and it was not well illustrated in my above question so I apologize for that. When the printer called `Final` has been specified in the report settings to be THE printer that the report will print on, the printer margins window shows up as it does in my final picture (with the `.66` in the bottom margin box). When I attempt to update this value, it is automatically reset to `.66` if I choose a lower value. It does this without me printing or even closing the window. If I exit that box, it will get reset back to `.66`. It may remain an issue.

Comment: Well, sounds to me like that printer might not support lower margins. If that's the case you're out of luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178632/discussion-between-edward-and-erik-von-asmuth).